# codeigniter image resize not working

Tags: codeigniter-2

can't understand why this image resizing not working pls help

```
//updating article

function updateArticle(){
$data = array(
    'a_title'           =>$_POST['a_title'],
    'a_description'     =>$_POST['a_description'],
    'a_flash_news'      => $_POST['a_flash_news'],
    'a_content'         =>$_POST['a_content'],
    //'a_views'             => $_POST['a_views'],
    'a_image_caption'   =>$_POST['a_image_caption'],
    'a_audio_caption'   =>$_POST['a_audio_caption'],
    'a_video'           =>$_POST['a_video'],
    'a_video_caption'   =>$_POST['a_video_caption'],
    'a_channel'         =>$_POST['a_channel'],
    'a_grouping'        =>$_POST['a_grouping'],
    'a_status'          =>$_POST['a_status'],
    'a_breaking'        =>$_POST['a_breaking'],
    'a_hot'             =>$_POST['a_hot'],
    'a_category_id'     =>$_POST['a_category_id'],
    'a_featured'        =>$_POST['a_featured'],
    'a_tags'            =>$_POST['a_tags'],
    'a_author'          =>$_POST['a_author'],
    'a_date'            =>$_POST['a_date']
    );


    //UPLOAD IMAGE
    //some $config vars for image
    $config['upload_path'] = './images/articles';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '0';
    $config['remove_spaces'] = true;
    $config['overwrite'] = false;
    $config['max_width'] = '0';
    $config['max_height'] = '0';

    //for image resize
    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['width'] = 320;
    $config['height'] = 320;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
    //upload main image
    if(!$this->upload->do_upload('a_image')){
        //$e = $this->upload->display_errors();
        //print_r($e);
    }

    $image = $this->upload->data();
    if($image['file_name']){
        $data['a_image'] = "images/articles/". $image['file_name'];
    }


    //UPLOAD THUMBNAIL
    unset($config);

    //now upload thumb
    //some $config vars for thumb
    $config['upload_path'] = './images/articles/thumb';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|wav';
    $config['max_size'] = '0';
    $config['remove_spaces'] = true;
    $config['overwrite'] = false;
    $config['max_width'] = '0';
    $config['max_height'] = '0';    
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload('a_thumbnail')){
        //$e = $this->upload->dispaly_errors();
        //print_r($e);exit();   
    }       

    $thumb = $this->upload->data();
        if($thumb['file_name']){
        $data['a_thumbnail'] = "images/articles/thumb/". $thumb['file_name'];
    }


    //UPLOAD AUDIO
    unset($config);

    //now upload thumb
    //some $config vars for thumb
    $config['upload_path'] = './audio';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'mp3|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|wav';
    $config['max_size'] = '0';
    $config['remove_spaces'] = true;
    $config['overwrite'] = false;
    $config['max_width'] = '0';
    $config['max_height'] = '0';    
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload('a_audio')){
        //$e = $this->upload->dispaly_errors();
        //print_r($e);exit();   
    }       

    $thumb = $this->upload->data();
        if($thumb['file_name']){
        $data['a_audio'] = "audio/". $thumb['file_name'];
    }

    //goes at last
    $this->db->where('id',$_POST['id']);
    $this->db->update('articles', $data);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what error are you getting?

have the upload paths 777 permissions?

I think if you need to rezise the images you need to set 777 permissions on the upload path.